# ESC/POS Printer status only returning unexpected two unsigned integers

Tags: java, python, printing, python-3.6, escpos

I have a kivy App that prints barcodes using ESC/POS command language.  The thing that I noticed is that if I don't get the printer status the App will send commands blindly without caring if the printer's out of paper or battery is flat ect.  So I use the `GS 0x99` command as prescribed by the manufacturer to read the printer status, but I am not sure if I understand the result correctly.  According to the manual it should return `1 D 99 XX FF`  of which the first five digits represent 
Bit `0` with value 0 or 1 for paper status; 
Bit `1` with value 0 or 1 for cover closed or not;
 Bit `2` with value 0 or 1 for printer temprature;
 Bit `3`  with value 0 or 1 for battery status; and
 Bit `4`  with value 0 or 1 for print status.
 I read the the InputStream into a python `Array` with `Unsigned Integer typecode` that always return two decimals `[153, 255]`.
 If I use python's `hex` method the values would hexadecimally be `[0x99, 0xff]`, but how do I interpret each bit or digit as a 0 or 1 value from the hexadecimal value?
 If I turn the returned integers into binary I get `f'{255:b}' returns '11111111'` and `f'{153:b}' returns '10011001'` which does not say much as I opened the lid and sent the  printer status command which gave me exactly the same result.
Edit:
So I had thought that maybe I was using the wrong java method to read the InputStream, as I am using `InputStreamReader` with `BufferedReader` which maybe will return the wrong result.  I tried using only `getInputStream` and got exactly the same result as above
 Edit 2:
 I changed the encoding from `latin-1` to `utf-8` and received a completely different result, which is the integer `65533`; `hex(65533) is 0xfffd`
 Printer details:
 Manufacturer: Urovo
Model: K319
PN:  48389221
 [Link to command](https://docdro.id/ohBBLas)
Can someone please point me in the right direction to interpret the results of the read? Should I use bitwise operators to assess each bit?

Comment: To get the answer, add your printer vendor and model number and command interface specifications. The usage is different from the general specification of ESC/POS, and it seems to be a specification specific to the vendor/model number. [GS a Enable/disable Automatic Status Back (ASB)](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=122)

Comment: @kunif I added the requested details.  Okay I did not know that ESC/POS usage was vendor/model specific.  Thanks for that info.

Comment: There may not be any documents accessible on the web. Please contact the support desk on these pages. [K319 Mobile Printer](https://en.urovo.com/product/detail/25.html), [Service &Support](https://en.urovo.com/page/aftersalesservice.html)

Comment: @kunif Thanks.  When I asked for the command manual, Urovo contacted the local distributor and requested that they send me the above manual in the link.  I don't see the ```GS a``` command in the manual.  But I will ask the distributor if this is the complete manual, just to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, there are the following possibilities.

- It is not a mode setting for notification by hardware.
- Since InputStream is used, the actual notification data is buried.

The notified data is binary data in bytes.
You need to treat it as a sequence of byte data.
If encoding is set assuming some characters, unintended conversion and error notification may occur.

According to the document, the status notification is the following 4 bytes of data, and the third byte is valid data.

```
0x1D, 0x99, 0xXX, 0xFF
```

For example, if `[0x99, 0xff]` you thought you received first, the first `0x1D` and the byte information in the status data are lost.

And if `0xfffd` obtained in the second is the last 2 bytes, the status seems to be `0xfd`, and it is as follows when judged in bit units, and it is difficult to think of it as an actual status value.

```
1 : Out of paper
0 : Cover (closed)
1 : Printer core overheating
1 : battery is low
1 : Print status (Probably during printing)
111 : =7  '/'  (Probably undefined or unsupported paper bin number)
```

Therefore, it seems that the data was changed by converting from `latin-1` to `utf-8`.
There is such an article.
[Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)

Input data is handled as binary data in bytes, not characters.
The status data will need to be processed bit by bit, as in your last sentence.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to mark your answer as correct.  I have been fiddling to read all the bytes from the array with Python, when I tried everything I noticed I had to use a java method to do this.  So I have the method but still trying to get it to work in python.  But I got feedback from the Urovo technicians which told me exactly what you said, they also told me to read more bytes from the buffer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know how does other printers that you have worked with status values look like?

Comment: [GS a](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=122) introduced in the comments and [GS r](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=124), [DLE EOT](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=118) for others. See the link for more details.